# Changing Page Title of Access Denied Page

Tags: theming

I have an odd request that appears to only be "solved" (aka not really) through changing the includes/common.inc file.

The instructions are something like...

> 1 Go to INCLUDES Folder
>   2. and make a copy of the file common.inc
>   3. use copy to make change.
>   4. edit the file with a text editor (not WORDPAD)
>   5. and go to "function drupal_access_denied()"
>   6. go to the 3th "IF" instruction
>
> and if you want change the TITLE of the "ACCESS DENIED" page
>
> change default (t('Access denied')) to something like: (t('Welcome
>   Visitor'))

Obviously it's a stupid and wasteful move to just go through changing a core file, so I was wondering... another answer mentioned adding something to the theme template.php file or the local.module file. If I wanted to change just the text for the page title of the default "Access Denied" references, how would I go about doing that without going into editing the core files?

And due to an odd way a module around the site was built, the custom 404 page idea just won't work, which is why I need the workaround the way I described it.

Thanks ahead of time!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 You can use GUI.

- Step 1:  First create a page and add whatever message you want.
- Step 2:  Customize the page alias as you see fit. Copy that URL.
- Step 3:  Go to admin/config/system/site-information and then go to
  the field    set for "Error Pages" and put in your custom page alias
  for the 403    page.